# Align submit button on float?

Tags: css

I want to align my submit button right next to the dropdownlist with CSS. It is going to the top at the moment. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Nww6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your button a class and apply `margin-top`:

```
.btn {
    margin-top:38px   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<div style="float:left">
  <label>Country
        <select id="cboCountry" >
        <option value="-">- All -</option>
    </select>
    </label> 
</div>
<div>
 <input type="submit' text="submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

write like this

```
input[type=submit]{
    margin-top:35px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input style="margin-top:38px" type="submit" value="Check availability" />
```

Comment: There is no need to define style in inside tags it's better to define it in separate CSS stylesheet.